# Vuetify dialog position: pop up near mouse?

Tags: vuetify.js

Does anyone have a recipe for positioning a Vuetify dialog near the mouse (i.e. near the activator component) rather than centered on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

using a **menu** could be an answer!

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus/#popover-menu

> A menu can be configured to be static when opened, allowing it to
> function as a popover. This can be useful when there are multiple
> interactive items within the menu contents.

Comment: short question, short answer. just to tell to use a menu is enough in this context. but yes, i can add a quote...